# How to update object property when a certain condition happens?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a robot that moves around in 2d and turns to either N,W,S or E. Default direction is N.
I have to make a function ,`turnLeft()`, that switches the direction to the left, so from N to W, from W to S and so on. My issue is that I am not being able to update the default direction when the function is invoked, so it always returns Facing West.

Any help or suggestion on how to update the direction everytime the function is called is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
let myRover ={direction: "N"}

// ======================

// ======================
function turnLeft(rover){
  if (rover.direction="N"){
     rover.direction= "W"
      console.log("Facing West");

  }
  else if(rover.direction="W"){
      rover.direction="S"
      console.log("Facing South");

  }
  else if(rover.direction="S"){
     rover.direction="E"
     console.log("Facing East");

  }
  else {
     rover.direction="N"
     console.log("Facing North");

  }

 console.log("turnLeft was called!");
}




turnLeft(myRover) // output:Facing West
turnLeft(myRover) // output:Facing West
```

Comment: You should use "===" instead of "="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in code `rover.direction="N"` replace this with `rover.direction==="N"` inside your if condition .

You are actually assigning 'N' to the direction each time, rather than comparing

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, you can assign variable in `if` statement. This is not what you want. Use `===` instead of `=`.
Also, mutate your original variable instead variable passed throw function.

Here a demo:

```js
let myRover = {direction: "N"}

function turnLeft(rover){
  if (rover.direction === "N"){
     myRover.direction = "W"
      console.log("Facing West");
    
  }
  else if(rover.direction === "W"){
      myRover.direction = "S"
      console.log("Facing South");
   
  }
  else if(rover.direction === "S"){
     myRover.direction = "E"
     console.log("Facing East");
    
  }
  else {
     myRover.direction = "N"
     console.log("Facing North");
    
  }

 console.log("turnLeft was called!");
}

turnLeft(myRover) // output:Facing West
turnLeft(myRover) // output:Facing West
```